# How to create a test view framework for an ASP.Net core 3.1 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-3.0

I have been trying to create a test view framework for an ASP.Net core 3.1 application. However, I am getting the error shown below. How do I fix these errors?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, do not send images like this, try sending the code and the log.
Try to be specific with the problem/error, don't say "How do I fix these errors?", try to read the logs to near down the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is the NuGet Error NU1201.

Issue: A dependency project doesn't contain a framework compatible with the current project. Typically, the project's target framework is a higher version than the consuming project.

Solution: Change the project's target framework to an equal or lower version than the consuming project.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1201